# SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for tmp\php1D18.tmp

Tags: laravel

I am getting

> SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php1D18.tmp

when try to insert data with image

Here's my controller method

```php
$studentimg = $request->file('studentimg');
$input['imagename'] = time() . '.' . $studentimg->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = public_path('/studentimages');
$studentimg->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
Student::create($request->all());
return back()->with('success', 'Image Upload successful');
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that we can't help you without a Minimal Reproducible Code Example

Comment: i am using a controller a with in a resource function i am trying to insert the image path into database then upload the file on public path but getting error SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php1D18.tmp
(

Comment: Still not helpful, show us your code so we can spot the problem

Comment: $studentimg = $request->file('studentimg');

        $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$studentimg->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $destinationPath = public_path('/studentimages');

         $studentimg->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
        Student::create($request->all());
       return back()->with('success','Image Upload successful');

Comment: Dont post code in comments, edit your question and add the code there. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer. Then, please update your question.